# Installing Portal for ArcGIS?

Tags: installation, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-portal

I installed ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4.1, ArcGIS for Server 10.4.1 and Web Adaptor, now I need to install Portal for ArcGIS, I looked for the trial version in the ESRI's website but in vain.

Is there any link I can access to get the Portal?

Comment: The only link is the same as the one that you used to obtain Server media. I'm not sure if eval licenses are issued for server products. Talking to you local rep would be the only way to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portal for ArcGIS comes at no additional cost to users of ArcGIS Server. Log into where you downloaded ArcGIS Server from. (https://my.esri.com), under My Organization -- Downloads --- Click "View Downloads" next to your ArcGIS Enterprise, the Portal download should be listed there.

[image]

Comment: I assume that it is available exclusivly for who purchased the product, I need just a trial version.

Comment: There's no trial version of ArcGIS Portal.